# Why is my outcome always going to "else"? (quiz app) (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having trouble with testing an if/else with my quiz app for school. It is set up with radio buttons for the answer choices and a submit button. When you click submit on the wrong answer, you get an alert saying "No", but you also get a "No" alert when you choose the correct answer, even though i set "Yes!" to alert when you choose the correct answer. Not sure what I'm writing wrong...

*EDIT* I noticed I put .val(' ') in my code below. I have fixed that issue after it being pointed out and im still getting the same results changing it to .val()

```
function submitAnswer() {
    $('.questionBox').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.altBox').hide();
        $('.outcomeBox').show();
        let selected = $('input:checked');
        let answer = selected.val('');
        let correct = STORE[questionNumber].correctAnswer;
        if (answer == correct){
            alert('Yes!');
        } else {
            alert('No!');
        }
    });
}
```

Heres the question:

```
let questionNumber = 0;
const STORE = [
    {
        title: 'What year was Donkey Kong released?',
        answers: [
            '1980',
            '1981',
            '1982',
            '1983'
        ],
        correctAnswer:
            '1981'
    },
```

And my Html/Question set up

```
function createSetup(){
    $('.questionBox').html(`
    <form id="quiz" action='#'>
        <div class="questionTitle">
            <p>Question Title</p><br>
    </form>
    `);
};

function showQuestion(){
    let question = STORE[questionNumber];
    $('.questionTitle p').text(question.title);
    for(var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
        $('#quiz').append(`<input type='radio' name='choices' id='${i}' required> ${question.answers[i]}<br>`)
    };
    $('#quiz').append(`<input type='submit'>`)
};
```

Comment: It seems that you always assign an empty string to `selected` and the returned object is then given to `answer` - in this line `let answer = selected.val('');` - that's not going to match the `correctAnswer`

Comment: `selected.val('')` does not return the value of `selected`, it clears it. Use `selected.val()` to get the `selected`'s value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my above answer this answers your question directly.

First, take your onclick event out of the function or it wont work properly.

Next, the main problem is that radio inputs do not have a value set so if you really want a value there you should add the correct answer you are looking for.

I have added a comment in the code below.

Good luck.

```js
let questionNumber = 0;
const STORE = [
    {
        title: 'What year was Donkey Kong released?',
        answers: [
            '1980',
            '1981',
            '1982',
            '1983'
        ],
        correctAnswer:
            '1981'
    }
];

function createSetup(){
    $('.questionBox').html("<form id='quiz' action='#'><div class='questionTitle'><p>Question Title</p><br></form>");
};

function showQuestion(){
    let question = STORE[questionNumber];
    $('.questionTitle p').text(question.title);
    for(var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
    
    // -------------------------------------------------
    // ADD A VALUE HERE BECAUSE THE RADIO HAS NO VALUE.
    // value='"+question.answers[i]+"' 
    // ----------------------------------------------------
        $('#quiz').append("<input type='radio' name='choices' id='"+i+"' value='"+question.answers[i]+"' required> "+question.answers[i]+"<br>");
    };
    $('#quiz').append("<input type='submit'>");
};

function submitAnswer() {
    // take on click out of the function.
}

$('.questionBox').on('submit', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        
        $('.altBox').hide();
        $('.outcomeBox').show();
        let selected = $('input:checked');
        let answer = selected.val();
        let correct = STORE[questionNumber].correctAnswer;
        
        console.log(answer);
        
        if (answer == correct){
            alert('Yes!');
        } else {
            alert('No!');
        }
    });

createSetup();
showQuestion();
```

```css
.questionBox {
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}

#quiz {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionBox">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer your question specifically but this is how I would have worked on this.

The main parts I would focus on are removing the IDs and use classes instead so that your work is more modular.

Also, making use of the data-attribute lets you store data on almost anything. I used it for the inputs and put the answer there as **data-answer="AnswerValueHere"**

Finally I would say for this sort of thing you dont really need to use the form and just stick with buttons and divs. You dont need a form to use a buttons or inputs.

Again this is not an answer per say but some hints on what I would do in this case. 
The comments above might fix your particular problem, however making some of these changes may prevent other problems from occurring further down your project.

Good Luck.

```js
/* ************************** */
/* TEST DATA HERE */
/* ************************** */

const STORE = [{
  title: 'What year was Donkey Kong released?',
  answers: [
    '1980',
    '1981',
    '1982',
    '1983'
  ],
  correctAnswer: '1981'
},
{title: 'What year was Pac man released?',
  answers: [
    '1980',
    '1981',
    '1982',
    '1983'
  ],
  correctAnswer: '1980'
}];
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/* ************************** */
/* SUBMIT THE ANSWER FUNCTION */
/* ************************** */
function submitAnswer(thisAnswer) {  
  
    var a = thisAnswer.closest(".quiz").find(".outcomeBox");
    var questionNumber = thisAnswer.closest(".quiz").attr("data-id"); // made this local instead of global so it is more modular.
    
    let selected = $('input:checked');
    let answer = selected.attr("data-answer");
    let correct = STORE[questionNumber].correctAnswer;
    
    // clear css for outcomeBox answers
      a.removeClass("correctAnswer");
      a.removeClass("wrongAnswer");
    if (answer == correct) {
      a.addClass("correctAnswer"); // add some correct answer css
      a.html("Yes, you are correct"); // add some text
      a.show(); // finally show box
    } else {
      a.addClass("wrongAnswer"); // add some wrong answer css
      a.html("No, you are wrong"); // add some text
      a.show(); // finally show box
    }
  
}

/* ************************** */
/* CREATE QUESTIONS           */
/* ************************** */
function showQuestion(x) {

  var question = STORE[x]; // grab the data from the questions at the x index provided in the function.
  
  var content = ""; // setting up a content variable
  
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // I removed the <form> and changed to div because it makes it easier to work with.
  // You do not need a form to use buttons/input and if you dont use a 
  // form you dont have to prevent default actions from happening.
  
  content += "<div class='quiz' data-id='"+x+"'>";
  content += "<p class='questionTitle'>"+question.title+"</p>"; // set the title
    
  for (var i = 0; i < question.answers.length; i++) {
  
    content += "<input type='radio' name='choices' data-answer='"
    content += question.answers[i];
    content += "' required> ";
    content += question.answers[i];
    content += "<br>";
    
  };
  
  content += "<button>submit</button>"; // add a button which acts like a submit.
  content += "<div class='outcomeBox'>a</div>"; // moved outcome box here so is modular
  content += "</div>";
  
  // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  $('.questionBox').append(content); // append the content to the quiz container
  
};


/* ******************************* */
/* If a submit answer is clicked   */
/* then check the answers.         */
/* ******************************* */
$('body').on('click', ".questionBox button", function() {
  
  var thisAnswer = $(this).closest(".quiz");
  
  submitAnswer(thisAnswer);
  
});

// show the questions.
showQuestion(0);
showQuestion(1);
```

```css
.outcomeBox {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.correctAnswer {
  border: 2px solid green;
  color: green;
}

.wrongAnswer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="questionBox"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `let answer = selected.val('') to let answer = selected.val();`

selected.val() returns the value whereas selected.val(value) sets the value.